# Laravel package Controller not found in route

Tags: php, laravel

I have a [simple package](https://github.com/Tropicalista/Admin) and I want to use the controller. When I try to use it in routes I got

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Tropicalista\Admin\Controllers\DashboardController 
does not exist
```

I have this in my /routes/web.php

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => '\Tropicalista\Admin\Controllers', 
    'prefix'=> 'admin'], function() {

        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.root', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);

});
```

My controller:

```
namespace Tropicalista\Admin\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Analytics;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{...}
```

I think is a namespace problem. So how can I call the package controller?

Comment: what is your route url?? show us something that can help us to understand

Comment: It looks like you might be missing the leading \ from your namespace. Post  your code.

Comment: please show your route url and controller namespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By default, the `RouteServiceProvider` includes your route files within
>   a `namespace` group, allowing you to register controller routes without
>   specifying the full `App\Http\Controllers` namespace prefix. So, you
>   `only` need to specify the portion of the namespace that `comes after` the
>   base `App\Http\Controllers` namespace.

You need to remove [namespace](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'admin'], function() {

    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.root', 'uses' => '\Tropicalista\Admin\Controllers\DashboardController@index']);

});
```

Comment: I should put ```use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;``` in controllers?

Comment: which controller you are referring?? your package controller or your own controller??

Comment: Package controller

Comment: I think we should not change anything in package controller as it is some kind of library, right??

Comment: The package is mine, I'm developing it for my purpose. I'm just learning what is the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a package, you need to [register the routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#routes) in the package.

You can see an example of registering package controllers [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php#L69):

```
$routeConfig = [
    'namespace' => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers',
    'prefix' => $this->app['config']->get('debugbar.route_prefix'),
    'domain' => $this->app['config']->get('debugbar.route_domain'),
    'middleware' => [DebugbarEnabled::class],
];
$this->getRouter()->group($routeConfig, function($router) {
    $router->get('open', [
        'uses' => 'OpenHandlerController@handle',
        'as' => 'debugbar.openhandler',
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to call package controller, change the namespace group of RouteServiceProvider from

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

to null/empty i.e.

```
protected $namespace = '';
```

Then, the route can be written as,

```
Route::get('homepage', 'Package\Namespace\Controllers\ControllerName@ActionName');
```

Further, if you want to write route for the default controller, use leading slash '/' before starting url.

```
Route::get('/homepage', 'App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName@ActionName');
```

Whether it is good practice or not but it solved the problem.